# How do I correctly bind a Popup to a ToggleButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, togglebutton

I am trying to do something that seems relatively simple and logic from a user interface level but I have one bug that is very annoying. I have a `ToggleButton` and I am trying to show a `Popup` when the button is toggled in and hide the `Popup` when the button is toggled out. The `Popup` also hides when the user clicks away from it.

Everything is working as expected with the following XAML except when I click the toggle button after the `Popup` is shown, the `Popup` disappears for a split second then reappears.

I suspect what's going on here is that clicking away from the `Popup` is causing it to toggle the button off then immediately after the button is toggled back on as the mouse clicks it. I just don't know how to go about fixing it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
    <ToggleButton x:Name="TogglePopupButton" Content="My Popup Toggle Button" Width="100" />

    <Popup StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TogglePopupButton, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Border Width="100" Height="200" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock>This is a test</TextBlock>
        </Border>                
    </Popup>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be as difficult as it is.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Stephans answers has the disadvantage, that the desired behaviour of closing the popup whenever it loses focus also disappears.

I solved it by disabling the toggle-button when the popup is open. An alternative would be to use the IsHitTestVisible Property instead of is enabled:

```
    <ToggleButton x:Name="TogglePopupButton" Content="My Popup Toggle Button" Width="100"  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ToggledPopup, Path=IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToInvertedBoolConverter}}"/>
    <Popup x:Name="ToggledPopup" StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TogglePopupButton, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Border Width="100" Height="200" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock>This is a test</TextBlock>
        </Border>                
    </Popup>
```

The converter looks like this:

```
public class BoolToInvertedBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            bool boolValue = (bool)value;
            return !boolValue;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("ConvertBack() of BoolToInvertedBoolConverter is not implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clever. I used the IsHitTestVisibile method because we need IsEnabled for other reasons.

Comment: This solves the problem, but the solution apparently depends on some tricky timing. When I replace the converter with equivalent view model binding, it no longer works. Apparently button down sets IsOpen = false, reenabling the ToggleButton, and button up triggers the ToggleButton. No idea why the converter version works. I am afraid the timing might bomb out later when new version of the framework is released or when this solution is used in non-trivial ways.

Comment: @RobertVažan I have put the popup into a custom control and now experience the problem you specified. It works if the popup is part of the outer control as this answer gives.

Comment: @RobertVažan The ViewModel version of this solution seems to work if you add a delay to the binding: `<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen, Delay=10}">`

Comment: Good Solution. But i get an issue when using these method in a template. Because every item of this template share the same name of the controls. Is there a way to do this with RelativeSource I tried it myself but didn't get it worked.

Answer (score 30):

Solution without IValueConverter:

```
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="TogglePopupButton" Content="My Popup Toggle Button" Width="100" >
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Popup, Path=IsOpen}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>

    <Popup StaysOpen="false" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TogglePopupButton, Mode=TwoWay}"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=TogglePopupButton}" PopupAnimation="Slide" 
           x:Name="Popup">
        <Border Width="100" Height="200" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBlock>This is a test</TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly and saves me from writing another converter. Great job!

Comment: Note - If you want the popup animation (set to Slide) to work, you'll have to set the AllowTransparency property of the popup to True. [SO Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069686/wpf-popup-open-with-animation)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. None of the answers offered here worked correctly.

After a little research, I can say that the suspicions of the author of the question are correct. During a mouse click, the first click (down) closes the popup and set togglebutton as unchecked, the second click (up) causes the observed action when the popup appears again.

The first way to avoid this problem is to discard the second click by delay:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="UserPhotoToggleButton"/>

<Popup x:Name="UserInfoPopup"
       IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=UserPhotoToggleButton, Delay=200, Mode=TwoWay}"
       StaysOpen="False">
```

It looks simple enough to fix problem. Although it is not an ideal solution. The best way would be to extend the functionality of the popup by Behavior:

Add these namespaces

```
xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:WpfClient.Resources.Behaviors;assembly=WpfClient.Resources"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

then extend your popup by *i:Interaction.Behaviors*

```
<Popup x:Name="UserInfoPopup"
       StaysOpen="False">
      <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:BindToggleButtonToPopupBehavior
                       DesiredToggleButton="{Binding ElementName=UserPhotoToggleButton}"/>
      </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Border>
            <!--Your template-->
            </Border> 
</Popup>
```

Finally add the behavior. In a minimal form, it may look like this:

```
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfClient.Resources.Behaviors
{
    public class BindToggleButtonToPopupBehavior : Behavior<Popup>
    {
        public ToggleButton DesiredToggleButton
        {
            get { return (ToggleButton)GetValue(DesiredToggleButtonProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DesiredToggleButtonProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DesiredToggleButtonProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DesiredToggleButton), typeof(ToggleButton), typeof(BindIconToggleButtonToPopupBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            
            DesiredToggleButton.Checked += DesiredToggleButton_Checked;
            DesiredToggleButton.Unchecked += DesiredToggleButton_Unchecked;

            AssociatedObject.Closed += AssociatedObject_Closed;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseUp;
        }

        private void DesiredToggleButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => AssociatedObject.IsOpen = false;

        private void DesiredToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => AssociatedObject.IsOpen = true;

        private void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Source is Button)
                AssociatedObject.IsOpen = false;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DesiredToggleButton != Mouse.DirectlyOver)
                DesiredToggleButton.IsChecked = false;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();

            DesiredToggleButton.Checked -= DesiredToggleButton_Checked;
            DesiredToggleButton.Unchecked -= DesiredToggleButton_Unchecked;
            
            if (AssociatedObject != null)
            {
                AssociatedObject.Closed -= AssociatedObject_Closed;
                AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp -= AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseUp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the ToggleButton set the Property `ClickMode="Press"`[apixeltoofar](https://apixeltoofar.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/the-great-wpf-togglebutton-and-popup-conundrum/)

Comment: This seems to work at the first glance, but while clicking the ToggleButton no longer re-opens the Popup, clicking anywhere else suddenly fails to close the Popup as intended. I don't understand why exactly that is happing and if it's fixable, but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
<Popup StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TogglePopupButton, Mode=oneway}">
```

the binding `Mode=TwoWay` makes the control to update the state each other

Answer (score -1):

Set `StaysOpen="True"` for your `Popup`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the Popup control closes
>   when the control is no longer in focus.
>
> [...]
>
> `true` if the `Popup` control closes when `IsOpen` property is set to `false`;
>
> `false` if the `Popup` control closes when a mouse or keyboard event occurs outside the `Popup` control.

Comment: The desired effect is to still have the popup close when focus is lost. The problem is when you use a `ToggleButton` to open the `Popup`, and you attempt to close the `Popup` by clicking on the `ToggleButton`. It will perform the action of the `StaysOpen="False"` and the click of the `ToggleButton` causing the `Popup` to close and then open again.